# Exclusion constraint for text values

Tags: postgresql-12, exclusion-constraint

I have two tables. A client table and a vehicle table, the two are linked in a unit lookup table.
My constraint is that a vehicle cannot belong to a client if it already is associated with another client.

This is what I have so far:

```
ALTER TABLE unit 
   ADD CONSTRAINT unit_vehicle_across_client_constraint 
   EXCLUDE USING GIST (client WITH =, vehicle WITH <>) DEFERRABLE;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I guess I just don't really understand how the exclusion parameters really work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested a simple UNIQUE constraint on vehicle does the trick. Not sure why I wanted to do complicated.